# Planarity of rings

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, molecular-structure, resonance

Can a **7** or less than **7** membered homocyclic ring with unsaturated C atoms and fully conjugated system, lose planarity? The smallest homocyclic non-planar ring that I know is **cyclooctatetraene** which is a 8C compound.

Comment: Planarity is not a boolean value.

Comment: Only cyclopentane is planar, all other saturated rings are at least puckered.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン You probably meant cyclopropane. And I think OP is asking about fully conjugated ring systems...

Comment: @orthocresol yes, yes I did. And I guess you are right about OP's intentions.

Comment: @IvanNeretin The mathematician in me says planarity is very much a boolean value' for 3 vectors **a**, **b** and **c** in 3D they are coplanar iff **a**. **b** x **c** is zero. You can talk about small deviations from planarity yes, especially if you quantify them in some way, but the property of planarity itself is a yes/no question.

Comment: @IanBush Good point. Well, since the real-world numbers are known with some uncertainty, they **never** exactly equal anything, in particular zero. Hence the strict mathematical definition of planarity is useless to us, and we resort to using the approximate version, which is where my first comment applies.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Hmmm, different worlds. I'm a computationalist. I can almost always tell you exactly when my atoms all lie in a plane. Possibly the reason behind me wanting to keep the concept to planarity "pure". I would still rather you say something like "with deviations from planarity measured as <some measure of error>".

Answer (score 2):

Setting aside rings with saturated carbon atoms, it appears that the **cyclobutadiene-dication ring** can be puckered despite being formally aromatic according to the $4n+2$ rule. Puckering may be favored by dispersion of the charge which, in the planar geometry, is highly concentrated in the four-carbon ring. From the abstract of [Firme et al.[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp075869j):

> The cyclobutadiene dication was not experimentally characterized to the date. However, some of its derivatives were. Most of them have planar geometry, but tetramethylcyclobutadiene dication has a nonplanar geometry according to ab initio calculations. ... The planar cyclobutenyl dication derivatives have bond order of chemical bonds in the ring close to unity and relatively small electronic density in the ring. The puckered cyclobutadiene dication and its puckered derivatives have relatively high electronic density in the ring.

**Reference**

1. Firme CL, Antunes OA, Esteves PM. Electronic nature of planar cyclobutenyl dication derivatives. J Phys Chem A. 2007 Nov 22;111(46):11904-7. doi: 10.1021/jp075869j. Epub 2007 Oct 19. PMID: 17948974.

Comment: I read somewhere that similar thing can happen with analogous dianion.